# Kubernetes 0 Downtime using Readiness Probe and RollBack strategy not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have set up a Node app on Kubernetes. I'm running a single replica and I want 0 down-time when the image is updated. I update my Pod using `set Image` on Kubernetes.

```
'set', 'image', 'deployment/dev-web'
```

Here's my YAML file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: dev-web
  name: dev-web
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: dev-web
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: dev-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        image: gcr.io/my-project-link/my-image-link
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: dev-web-container
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2000
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 2000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 20m
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-12-07T11:13:21Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-12-07T11:13:21Z
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 2
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

My app does give 200 response on '/' get therefore Readiness Probe works but when I update the Image, and test it but continuously hitting CURL, it gives me downtime which lasts for like 20-40 seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You setup your `maxUnavailable` as 1 even when you have only one replica, you should be having `maxUnavailable` to 0.

```
strategy:
 type: RollingUpdate
 rollingUpdate:
   maxUnavailable: 0
   maxSurge: 1
```

It basically tells Kubernetes that there should be zero unavailable pods while deploying (`maxUnavailable: 0`) and there should be one new pod at a time (`maxSurge: 1`).

I am hoping you setup the `readiness` probe something like this:

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: 80
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
```

Basically, this is a check that Kubernetes does in order to make sure that your pod is ready to send traffic to it. Until it is not ready, Kubernetes will not use your pod.

Comment: I did this but as a result, my node app didnot restart. The code wasn't updated. When I see the container logs, I don't see a new App being restarted.

Comment: YOu need to setup the readiness probe as well, just I showed in my edit of answer

Comment: thanks, can you please check as readiness Probe is in that YAML file

Comment: So you have provided `failureThreshold` to 3 and `periodSeconds` 5 and `initialDelay` 5, it means kubelet do 3 polls to pods at 10sec 15sec and 20 sec and gives up. Your app doesn't come up in that time I believe. try increasing this threshold according to your application